# Can´t get Liferay ArticleDisplay in 6.1.20 EE

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I do get the following exception in Liferay 6.1.20 EE when I try to get a JournalArticleDisplay with a template. The template exists, the JournalArticle exists - everything is fine ;) And the same code works in 6.1.30 EE ;)

But as soon as I call this method in 6.1.20 EE, it breaks because companyId shall not be 0 :

```
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.templateparser.TransformException: Unhandled exception
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.templateparser.BaseTemplateParser.transform(BaseTemplateParser.java:135)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.templateparser.BaseTransformer.transform(BaseTransformer.java:163) 
at com.liferay.portlet.journal.util.JournalUtil.transform(JournalUtil.java:1036)
at com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.impl.JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.getArticleDisplay(JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.java:1090)
... 87 more
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.NoSuchCompanyException: No Company exists with the primary key 0
at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.CompanyPersistenceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(CompanyPersistenceImpl.java:486)
at com.liferay.portal.service.base.CompanyLocalServiceBaseImpl.getCompany(CompanyLocalServiceBaseImpl.java:385)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor232.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:122)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.getCompany(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.service.CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompany(CompanyLocalServiceUtil.java:181)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.templateparser.BaseTemplateParser.getCompany(BaseTemplateParser.java:150)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.templateparser.BaseTemplateParser.populateTemplateContext(BaseTemplateParser.java:244)
at com.liferay.portlet.journal.util.VelocityTemplateParser.populateTemplateContext(VelocityTemplateParser.java:178)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.templateparser.BaseTemplateParser.transform(BaseTemplateParser.java:120)
... 90 more
```

Comment: You are calling JournalArticleDisplay based on template, make sure the structure & template exist in the same site where your article is created. also template name is correct. can you please share the complete logs there will be more details in logs, which could help to identify the exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry if I caused trouble.

This seems to be a Liferay Bug : https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-25275

We will upgrade our server ...